# How to create Crowdsale contract for ERC-1155 fungible tokens

Tags: solidity, ico, nft, erc-1155

I am new to develop ERC-1155 contracts. I have created a contract that holds two types of tokens (fungible and Non-fungible tokens).

Now I want to add a crowdsale functionality in my contract, where users can send ETH to get equivalent fungible tokens. Should I have to add this method in my **token contract** or should I implement a new **Crowdsale contract** for this? Which method would be better?

If creating Crowdsale contract is better, then will **Crowdsale contract** can distinguish itself the type of tokens (e.g: token id) of **token contract**, or I have to implement some method for it too?